# Как обновить Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Как обновить ubuntu12.04 до ubuntu14.04?

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

стандартная процедура:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: `An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu `

Comment: в результате выполнения какой из указанных команд появилось это сообщение?

Comment: если в результате третьей, то попробуйте закомментировать строки с *ppa-репозиториями*, которые упомянуты в `/etc/apt/sources.list`. найти файлы с такими упоминаниями можно с помощью такой примерно команды: `grep -ril ppa /etc/apt/sources.list*`.

Comment: строки с _ppa_ уже были закомментированы в `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: а в каталоге `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: удалить оттуда файлы с ppa в названии?

Comment: на ваше усмотрение: можно удалить. можно закомментировать. только не забудьте после внесения исправлений в `/etc/sources.list*` обновить список пакетов командой `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: тоже самое после do-release-upgrade.... An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. This can be caused by: * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

Comment: посмотрите, остались ли в системе «поломанные» пакеты: `grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`. если да, удалите их командой `sudo apt-get remove <список поломанных пакетов>`.

Comment: их очень много...

Comment: так ведь зато и инструменты есть подходящие и очень мощные. `sudo apt-get remove $(grep -i ^broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u)`

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите обновить из консоли, то с помощью команды

```
sudo do-release-upgrade.
```

Еще в разделе "Параметры - Программы и обновления" на вкладке "Обновления" можете выбрать, обновляться до релиза с длительным сроком поддержки (LTS) или любого.